# Convert python Code To Mathematica?

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert simple python code to  Mathematica code

Comment: Is "Simpyle" a typo, or is it something in the Python world I should know about?

Comment: You can also evaluate Python code in Mathematica using > at the beginning of a cell ( https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/external-system-integration/evaluate-python-in-a-notebook.html?product=language ) or using ExternalEvaluate as shown here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/Python.html and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ExecuteAPythonFileWithExternalEvaluate.html

Answer (score 15):

I do not think there is general way to convert large chunk of code from Python to Mathematica (such as complete functions). But for individual expressions you could try this do it via Latex.

In Python

```
In[24]: from sympy import *
In[25]: x,y=symbols('x y')
In[26]: expr= 1+2**(x+y)*integrate(sin(x),x)-2*tan(x)
In[27]: expr
Out[27]: -2**(x + y)*cos(x) - 2*tan(x) + 1
In[28]: sympy.latex(expr)
Out[28]: '- 2^{x + y} \\cos{\\left(x \\right)} - 2 \\tan{\\left(x \\right)} + 1'
```

Now transfer the last expression to Mathematica. You could do this via file, or manually, or in other ways. Once inside Mathematica, then type

```
expr = "-2^{x+y} \\cos{\\left(x \\right)}-2 \\tan{\\left(x \\right)}+1";
ToExpression[expr, TeXForm]
```

Which gives

```
 1+(-2)^(x+y) Cos[x]-2 Tan[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#module-sympy.printing.mathematica

example:

```py
from sympy import integrate, sin, tan, mathematica_code
from sympy.abc import x, y

print(mathematica_code((1 + 2 ** (x + y) * integrate(sin(x), x) - 2 * tan(x))))
```

get

```
-2^(x + y)*Cos[x] - 2*Tan[x] + 1
```

All supported functions are here,  `sympy.printing.mathematica.known_functions`